# Как задать стили QPlainText?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, qt-designer

Мне нужно задать стили `только для текста` не трогая весь едит. Как это можно сделать с программы `Qt Designer`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может попробуете таки подерать свойство font?

Comment: Хм не понял что вы имели ввиду

Comment: qtextbrowser можно

Comment: @qtextbrowse можно поподробней?

Comment: на изображении вы показали выделенный текст ? и хотите чтобы также было при наборе?

Comment: Я его не выделял это обводка для текста. И я хочу задать её отдельно от QPlainTextEdi

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html как и  QTextEdit виджет поддерживает базовый хтмл/ксс по базе. QPlainTextEdit - неподдерживает оформления текста хтмлом

Comment: @eri sorry, вы о чем ? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#appendHtml

Comment: ок, был неправ. странный виджет... зачем в нем хтмл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял, то что вы сказали `задать стили только для текста не трогая весь едит.`

Но попробуйте так:

**1.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3.** Нажимаем `Ctrl+R` и начинаем что-нибудь писать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

В Qt Designer не получилось, но руками можно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Template(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textbox = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.textbox.appendHtml(f"<span style='background-color: rgb(155, 155, 155);'>Hello World</span>")
        fixedFont = QFontDatabase.systemFont(QFontDatabase.FixedFont)
        fixedFont.setPointSize(15)
        fixedFont.setBold(True)
        self.textbox.setFont(fixedFont)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.textbox) 

        self.textbox.setFocus() #@
        self.textbox.selectAll()
        selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
        color = QColor(155, 155, 155).lighter()
        selection.format.setBackground(color)
        selection.cursor = self.textbox.textCursor()
        self.textbox.setExtraSelections([selection])
        cursor = self.textbox.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(cursor.position())
        self.textbox.setTextCursor(cursor)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # палитра для переключения на темные цвета:
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.blue)                            # Qt.white
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
    app.setPalette(palette)

    gui = Template()
    gui.resize(350, 350)
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно задать background-color именно для текста. А инпуту задать другой цвет

Comment: @Viannedi Попробуйте как-то изобразить и показать то, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Хорошо сейчас дополню скриншот к вопросу. Там просто едит, он залит в один цвет. И отдельные стили к тексту

Comment: @Viannedi гляньте update

Comment: Спасибо оно работает))

Comment: А нет не помогло  'PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'appendHtml'

Comment: @Viannedi у меня нет `PySide`, поэтому предлагаю вам заменить строку `self.textbox.appendHtml(f"<span style='background-color: rgb(155, 155, 155);'>Hello World</span>")` на `self.textbox.appendPlainText("Hello World")`

Comment: @Viannedi  у вас получилось?

Comment: да спасибо уже решил проблему

Comment: @Viannedi мой ответ вам чем-то помог ?

Comment: Да ваш ответ мне помог

Comment: @Viannedi  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Я открыл еще один вопрос, не могли бы вы мне помочь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114768/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b-pyqt