вызов async функции фризит приложение pyside6 (pyqt5)
есть модуль functions.py, который весь ассинхроный и есть приложение PySide6 (PyQT5) по нажатию на кнопку которого нужно вызвать ассинхронную функцию, однако тк софт PyQT5 работает в бесконечном цикле .exec() вызов функции перекрывает сам софт (то бишь софт тупо залагивает и ждет функцию).
Как правильно вызвать ассинхронную из модуля funtions.py дабы не перекрыть сам софт?
python v3.12.2, pyside6 v6.7.2

Посмотрите тут пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1114843/1365

@insolor он не работает :(

Чтоб не фризило нужно запускать async на qt лупе. Либо qt на асинкио лупе.
В первом варианте это делалось через asyncqt
Для новых версий Qt через родную интеграцию:
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_async_minimal.html
